# « même s'il est très laid » ou « même s'il était considéré comme très laid »?

Tags: sens

Cette question est soulevée dans le contexte de la phrase ci-dessous dont l'auteur est la linguiste (et historienne de l’orthographe française) Nina Catach (1923-1997):

**Le Sacré-Cœur, même très laid, est un monument historique.**

Il me semble qu'il faille croire que la seconde possibilité est la plus probable, mais y aurait-il un principe qui permette d'éliminer ce facteur de doute ?

Sinon quelqu'un aurait-il un avis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le présent est de rigueur ici.

> Le Sacré-Cœur, même **s'il est** très laid, est un monument historique.

Puisqu'on a un présent dans « est un monument historique. »

De plus, mais c'est un avis personnel, le Sacré-Cœur était, est et sera toujours très laid.

Comment: Et en plus il n'y a aucun facteur de doute dans l'expression de la linguiste..